# NSKeyedArchiver for multiple objects, without NSMutableArray

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, disk, nskeyedarchiver

I need to save to disk a large amount of custom objects (the amount is the reason why I cant just fill an array and then save it).
My custom object contains info about a person, such as name and age.
I want to save all objects in the same file at Documents directory using NSKeyedArchiver.
Ideally, I want to have no more than 100 objects on memory, so if I have to save 2000 objects to disk, I will save 20 packages of 100 objects.
I also want the key for each object to be object.name.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you need to write some code. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: How to save and then retrieve this info. If I set each object for his name property as key, I would need to store the keys on another structure to be able to unarchive my file, right??? Or there is a way to [unarchiver allObjectsForAllKeys]???